# How to add an icon for a social media button from a local folder in my desktop?

Tags: html, svg, button, icons, png

I've seen dozens of similar questions and results working with png and svg, but nothing worked properly here. I have both the png and the svg files on my desktop, but can't figure out a way to add them as buttons. Or better yet, I was able to add them to my page, but it doesn't appear, in its place only a blank space with the correct redirect link (but no image).

I've tried adding to the head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\rod\Desktop\Sites\rz\icons\found\Black_Icon.svg">
```

And then later in the code:

```
<a class="found-icon" href="https://found/rz_"
```

But alas no luck. This is an icon that is not on font awesome, and all I managed to find seemed to be almost exclusively connected to "how-to" regarding font awesome.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, if you're trying to make a social media button you can import an image and make it a clickable icon with the `<a>` tag.

To import images it goes as shown:

```
<a href="#insertwebsitehere" target="_blank"> <!-- when clicked it'll open the website in a new page -->
  <img src="/icons/found/Black_Icon.svg" alt="Black Icon"> <!-- this is your icon, if not loaded it'll just render Black Icon as text -->
</a>
```

In your example given, you tried to import the image via your local computer however, in HTML you have to import it a different way.

Imagine you had folder with name.html and another folder named images with all your images in it.

If you were to import images from that folder within your code attributes (src and href) found in name.html it would go as shown `images/icon.png` which locates the icon.png file within the images folder.

I hope this helps, happy coding!